# Amcharts4 stops responding to browser resize events

Tags: amcharts4

The first call to build the chart is fine, but subsequent calls to chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart) cause the chart to stop responding to browser resize events.

I've forked an example from the amcharts website here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPVpYX

I have tested this on Chrome, Firefox and Edge with the same result.

The only way I've found that fixes this - as shown in the linked code - is the chart.dispose() method, but this call takes 30 seconds to complete on larger datasets and is therefore not viable!

```
if (chart) {
  console.log('dispose start');
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  chart.dispose();
  console.log('dispose end ' + (new Date().getTime() - d));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating another chart on the same `<div>`, you would definitely _have to_ run `chart.dispose()` on the prior chart so you don't run into any issues. But for some reason disposing the chart can take as long as the time to load the chart, after which the new chart works fine even with resizing.

Comment: I was overwriting it because chart.dispose() takes 30 seconds! Building it took only 5.

I also posted on the amcharts4 github issue page. They've replied that there's a bug in chart.dispose() taking all that time. Hopefully a fix will come soon.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for doing that. Here's the issue in question if anyone else comes across this problem: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1228